# Are my logical translations correct?

Tags: first-order-logic

I am reading Halmos’ *Naive Set Theory*. I attempt to translate the axioms of set theory ***as Halmos puts them*** in formal first-order logic containing equality and belonging. Please check if these are correct:

1. > **Axiom of Extension:** *Two sets are equal if and only if they have the same elements.*

   *Immediate* translation: $$\forall A\forall B(A=B\leftrightarrow\forall x(x\in A\leftrightarrow x\in B))$$
2. > **Axiom of specification:** *To every set $A$ and to every condition $S(x)$ there corresponds a set $B$ whose elements are exactly those elements $x$ of $A$ for which $S(x)$ holds.*

   *Immediate* translation: $$\forall A\exists B(x\in B\leftrightarrow x\in A\wedge S(x))$$
3. *Ad hoc* axiom (to be later replaced by axiom of infinity):

   > *… there exists a set.*

   *Immediate* translation: $$\exists A$$
4. > **Axiom of pairing:** *For any two sets there exists a set that they both belong to.*

   *Immediate* translation: $$\forall A\forall B\exists C(A\in C\wedge B\in C)$$
5. > **Axiom of unions:** *For every collection of sets there exists a set that contains all the elements that belong to at least one set of the given collection.*

   *Immediate* translation: $$\forall A\exists B\forall x(\exists C(x\in C\wedge C\in A)\rightarrow x\in B)$$

---

**Note:** Though Halmos doesn’t *explicitly* assume that the theory is one-sorted (only sets are the “objects” of the theory), I bravely assume it. Otherwise I’d to use statements such as $\forall A(A \text{ is a set …})$.
Is my assumption okay if I *just want to* **translate** what Halmos writes?

Answer (score 2):

*Comments*

The usual form of [Pairing](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/ZF.html) is :

> "given any set x and y, there exists a pair set of x and y, i.e., a set which has only x and y as members".

In this case we have : $∀A∀B∃C∀w \ (w ∈ C ↔ w=A ∨ w=B)$.

But see Halmos, page 9 : from the "more liberal" version he uses (and correctly formalized by you) the usual version is derived through *Separation*.

---

The "usal" formulation of FOL is that every interpretation has a not-empty domain. This means that the *ad hoc* Existence axiom is not needed.

Having said that, if we want to expess it, $∃A$ is not a well-formed formula.

We need :

> $∃A(A=A)$.

Comment: Rest is correct?

Comment: @Atom - yes; you can check them with the linked SEP's entry.

Comment: Is my formalisation of axiom of pairing *equally* valid?